# Get data also outside of React components from Relay.js store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs

I have use case where I want to use some data from Relay store outside of the react components.  So thinking how to get data to some store.

One option would be to put these data to the 'store' in component once component gets the data.

But I would like more to be able create store similar to react component which defines its requirements, but does not render and can be required from any other file.

I thought I could use react component for it, but to instantiate component I need to render it to dom, which does not make sense in this situation.

Any ideas how to achieve that nicely?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is exactly what you want: [acdlite/relay-sink](https://github.com/acdlite/relay-sink)

Comment: Great, thanks for the link. Seems that its currently only way - use react component to *sink* data from relay.

Comment: Ideally, you would use `Relay.Store` methods to fetch/read arbitrary data. Currently, this is not possible because the `RelayQuery` type that these rely on is internal/private. It's this way in the initial release because we wanted to make the surface API area small, and have very well-defined behavior so that we can do things like garbage collection based on the subscribed components. We do want to make this more flexible though in the future. Feel free to [open a GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/new) with your use case if you'd like something visible to track this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with data I suggest you look into using a flux pattern. This would allow you to separate data logic from view logic.

Comment: I have been using flux extensively and still using for handling local data, but if I am fetching all server side data via Relay.js, and just need some specific data get out of react component I don't want to fetch them separately and use old patterns if I could get it directly from Relay store. So what I am currently doing is that I pass these data in my React root component to that store, so it can be accessed on other places, but think it could be better as described in my question.

Comment: I really need to pay better attention. I haven't set up a relay project yet so spoke to soon.